# Looping through multiple arrays in a single JSON file (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, fetch

I am trying to populate my HTML template with data from a JSON file I have created. However, I have two different arrays in that file, each of them containing multiple objects, and I do not know how to loop through them since I need to loop through them in separate functions.

The JS code I have provided below works if I were to have one big array in the JSON file ("product" being the array I am looping through), the problem is that I need to loop through the "glass" and the "wood" arrays separately (in different functions). Ideally, the JS snippet below would loop through the "wood" array.

I have only fetched from one big array before, so I don't really know how to approach this issue. I know this must be something super easy, but I am stuck and would appreciate any hints I can get! Thanks in advance.

JS file:

```
function init() {
if (window.location.href.includes("wood")) {
    fetchJson();
  }
}
function fetchJson() {
  fetch("products.json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(getWoodGallery(product));
}
function getWoodGallery(product) {
  product.forEach(showWoodGallery);
}
/*--- display wood products ---*/
function showWoodGallery(product) {
  console.log(product);
  const woodTemplate = document.querySelector("#woodGalleryTemplate").content;
  const woodTemplateCopy = woodTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  const woodList = document.querySelector("#woodList");

  woodTemplateCopy.querySelector("h2.name").textContent =
    "Name: " + `${product.wood}`;
  woodTemplateCopy.querySelector("p.dimensions").textContent =
    "Dimensions: " + `${product.dimensions}`;
  woodTemplateCopy.querySelector("h3.price").textContent =
    "Price: " + `${product.price}`;
  woodTemplateCopy.querySelector(".btn").textContent = `Buy Now`;

  woodList.appendChild(woodTemplateCopy);
}
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "wood": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "image": "http://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/animales_1.jpeg",
      "name": "Butterfly",
      "dimensions": "30 x 45cm",
      "price": 40,
      "btn": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "image": "http://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/symmetry_4.jpeg",
      "name": "Escher deconstructed",
      "dimensions": "30 x 45cm",
      "price": 20,
      "btn": ""
    }
  ],
  "glass": [
    {
      "id": "20",
      "image": "http://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/vidrio_17.jpeg",
      "name": "Juntos pero no revueltos",
      "dimensions": "30 x 45cm",
      "price": 20,
      "btn": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "image": "http://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/vidrio_11.jpeg",
      "name": "White & green",
      "dimensions": "30 x 45cm",
      "price": 20,
      "btn": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the JSON objects keys and conditionally run the function you need to run for that particular key.

```
function parse(payload) {
   Object.keys(payload).forEach((key) => {
        switch(key) {
           case 'wood':
             handleWood(payload[key]);
             break;
           case 'glass':
              handleGlass(payload[key]);
              break;
            // so on... 
        }
   })

}
```

Here, `Object.keys` will give you an array of all the keys of the object. We then iterate over the returned array with `forEach` running the callback for each iteration. Inside the callback we are just matching the key and running the required function.